# uploading images in database mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am building a script using php to upload images in database but i am stuck due to the error under:
when i open my page in browser following message shows to me:

**Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\12\index.php on line 10
please select a file**

under is my script in initial form :

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File:<input type="file" name="image" /><input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("databaseimage") or die(mysql_error());
//files properties
echo $file = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
if(!isset($file))
echo'please select a file';
else{
    $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check, if there is an upload first (and therefore, `$_FILES["image"]` is existing at all):

```
if (isset($_FILES["image"]))
{
    $file = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    if (!isset($file)) {
        echo 'please select a file';
    } else {
        $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    }
}
```